# A simple JavaScript function which is between parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have downloaded an external JavaScript file and want to create a HTML5 User Interface for it. I don't understand why the JavaScript code (see bellow) initiates his main function like that.

```
//JavaScript Code
(function(Raphael) {
      // some codes here
})(window.Raphael);
```

Why is that function between parentheses?

What does the "window.Raphael" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a [self invoking anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function).

You are passing in `window.Raphael` into this function which is essentially "renamed" to Raphael inside the function.

Comment: theoritically it is incorrect to call it *self-invoking* since it is not the function that is calling itself. Instead it is the thread (could be another function or global scope) it is defined in.

Comment: And the reason for this is most likely so that a minification tool then could shorten all uses of `Raphael` to a much shorter variable name within that function, without breaking the code.

Answer (score -1):

That is an immediately executing function (IIFE). Meaning one thats defined and executed immediately afterwards.

In this case, its also using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) which is an SVG library. The IIFE accepts a global variable presumably defined by Raphael that is accessible at `window.Raphael`

Comment: downvoted because IEF is YAUA (Yet Another Unnecessary Acronym).

Comment: Agreed. I just didn't want to keep typing "immediately executing function" again and again.. :-)

Comment: Just for arguments sake the most common acronym is IIFE - immediately-invoked function expression.

Comment: @Adam - Right, thats what i intended.

Comment: I've never seen that acronym, seems to be something you only see in JavaScript. Other languages that can do this don't ever define the acronym since it's a normal course of action.