# use 2 jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask on how I can use both functions once the page loads

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('#list').tableScroll({height:500});

});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('#list').tableSorter();

});
```

Comment: It's not the shortest way to write it, but your two separate pieces of code would work if you put them both in the page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#list').tableSorter().tableScroll({height:500});
});
```

Comment: Much better than my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery supports method chaining.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#list')
        .tableScroll({height:500})
        .tableSorter();    
});
```

Comment: You're right.. this is true only if the plugins you are using supports chainability

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('#list').tableScroll({height:500});
    $('#list').tableSorter();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put both under one DOM ready handler and use chaining:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").tableScroll({ height: 500 }).tableSorter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").tableScroll({ height: 500 }).tableSorter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').tableScroll({height:500}).tableSorter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its fine to have more than one

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) { .... }`

both will be called on page on load body :). irrespective of no of call`s made, all will be called on page load only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter version of `jQuery(document).ready(function())` that you could use that would have the same result:

```
 $(function() {
   // code to execute when the DOM is ready
 });
```

For this situation, using the elegant chaining:

```
$(function() {
    $('#list').tableSorter().tableScroll({height:500});
 });
```

For a discussion of the difference between these two approaches, [see this very helpful question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function)

Comment: but maybe toink uses other libraries so that `$` has to be escaped?

Comment: Well, @elektronikLexikon, there is always the possibility of collisions when multiple libraries are used, but that is not the question here.

Comment: it could be the reason why he used `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` in his question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
// Create an immediately-invoked function expression
(function ($) {

    // Enable strict mode
    "use strict";

    // Cache the selector so the script
    // only searches the DOM once
    var myList = $('#list'); 

    // Chain the methods together
    myList.tableScroll({height:500}).tableSorter();

}(jQuery));
```

Writing your jQuery in an IIFE like this means you can run the code alongside other libraries that also use `$`, and you won’t get conflicts.

Be sure to include this JavaScript at the end of your document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.