# scroll bar is not at bottom of div when page loads

Tags: jquery

**I want to get scroll bar at bottom of div as soon as page loads but it is not working**

My design:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="dvMsgBody" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div id="dvMessage" class="col-lg-12" style="height: 500px; overflow: auto; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
//not working
{
    $("#divChatWindow").find('#dvMsgBody').find('#dvMessage').scrollTop($('#dvMessage')[0].scrollHeight);
}


//not working
{
    $("#divChatWindow").find('#dvMsgBody').find('#dvMessage').animate({ scrollTop: $('#dvMessage')[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
}

//not working
{
    $('#dvMessage').scrollTop($('#dvMessage')[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you want a scroll bar at the bottom of the div? Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of what you're current implementation looks like

Comment: when do you call those functions? what is the event?

Comment: Tip: IDs should be unique, therefore a single selector like `$('#dvMessage')` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaLbb4ra/)

```
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#dvMessage').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#dvMessage').prop('scrollHeight') }, 1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `window.load()` event within a `document.ready()` one. You should use one or another instead.

Comment: @MelanciaUK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function

Comment: Sorry. I've seen what's not there - `$(function())`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have create a simply jsFiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/azp9vjyk/

jQuery

```
$(function()
  {
    $('.scroll').animate({ scrollTop: $('.scroll').prop('scrollHeight') }, 5000);
});
```

Html

```
<div class="scroll">Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. </div>
```