# add element offset to jQuery offset calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am rather new to jquery and i'm trying to find the right offset for a div element inside the body. I want to make this div element sticky whenever I scroll down and pass the top offset of this element.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utonytGKodc and it works but I have a metaslider in my header and the width/height of this element is left out of the calculations to find the right offset....

the result is that my element becomes a sticky element way to soon, is there a way I can manualy add the sliders coordinates (offset) to the offset calculation of the element i want to make sticky?

```
var offerteOffset = jQuery(".agendawrap").offset().top //+ metaslider coordinates??;
    alert(offerteOffset);

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= offerteOffset) {
            jQuery(".agendawrap").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery(".agendawrap").removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe people make such bad tutorials.

First of all: dont write `jQuery` all the time. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function).
Basically it says: use an invoking function with an own scope:

```
(function($) { /* all your jQuery goes here */ })(jQuery);
```

So you can just type `$` instead of `jQuery`.

To your original question:

```
(function($) { 

  $(function() { // document ready...

    var scrollTolerance = 50,
      agendawrap = $(".agendawrap"),
      offerteOffset = agendawrap.offset().top;

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

        // OR: if (scrollPos - scrollTolerance >= offerteOffset) {
        if (scrollPos + scrollTolerance >= offerteOffset) {
          agendawrap.addClass("fixed");
        } 
        else {
          agendawrap.removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Allright thanks a lot, can you link me to a good tutorial because i would like to know how this works instead of just copy/paste

Comment: ow, and i use it in wordpress i think that is why i use jQuery instead of $? @alex

Comment: @W.Romijn doesnt matter in which environment you use it, you can use the above way everywhere, it is current best practice. i highly recommend you that you try to understand what is happening there. i really like that you try to understand rather than just copy/paste, so I offer you a little chat session if you are interested :)

Comment: Yea that sounds great! How can I start a chatsession? @Alex