# AngularJS: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module _ is not available! | Multiple References to Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am currently trying to reference a single AngularJS module within various directives and services like the one below.

**module.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('operations.setup.holidays.calendar', []);

})();
```

When I try to reference it in one directive/service/controller it works fine, but when I try to reference it in say a directive and a service I get: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'operations.setup.holidays.calendar' is not available!`

**directive.js** *(works if this is the only thing referencing `'operations.setup.holidays.calendar'`)*

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('operations.setup.holidays.calendar')
        .directive('yearlyCalendarDirective', yearlyCalendarDirective);

    function yearlyCalendarDirective(){
        return{
          template: "<h1>Year Calendar Directive</h1>"
        };
    }
})();
```

**service.js** *(adding something like this causes the specified error)*

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('operations.setup.holiday.calendar')
        .service('Calendar',Calendar);

    function Calendar(){

    }
})();
```

> Adding something like `.module('operations.setup.holiday.calendar',[])` gets rid of the error, but from what I understand this creates a new module instead of referencing the old one?

**Edit:**
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeviBarker/wm4de7pk/9/)

Comment: Have you loaded module.js before your other files?

Comment: @devqon Yes, I thought that might be the issue but module.js is the first one loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621412/1015690), calling anonymous functions doesn't guarantee the functions will be calling in the order.

maybe you can load all code in one anonymous function:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('CalendarApp', []);

  angular.module('CalendarApp').directive('yearlyCalendar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<span>Here is a YEARLY calendar</span>'
    }
  });

  angular.module('CalendarApp').directive('monthlyCalendar', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      template: '<span>Here is a MONTHLY calendar</span>'
    }
  });

  angular.module('CalendarApp').service('CalendarData', function() {
    function CalendarData() {
      vm = this;
      vm.today = new Date();
      return new CalendarData();
    }
  });
})();
```

if you have this code separated in many files, don't use anonymous functions (calling the code directly instead)

Comment: Thanks @Diego! That seemed to work!  So if I wanted to keep them separated I would just remove the anonymous function closures? `(function() {})();`

Comment: yes.. just call the code inside that anonymous functions directly