# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property X of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep receiving this error for my mobile navigation:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

I cannot find the cause. The error is referring to the last 3/4 lines of code.

```
var theToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}

function addClass(elem, className) {
    if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

function removeClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
}

function toggleClass(elem, className) {
    var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace( /[\t\r\n]/g, " " ) + ' ';
    if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
        while (newClass.indexOf(" " + className + " ") >= 0 ) {
            newClass = newClass.replace( " " + className + " " , " " );
        }
        elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    } else {
        elem.className += ' ' + className;
    }
}

theToggle.onclick = function() {
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
}
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: An element with the id of 'toggle' can not be found on your page by your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Your .js loaded before DOM was initialized, and `document.getElementById('toggle')` found nothing, as there is no element with this id yet.

Place this `<script>` in the end of HTML.

Answer (score 1):

1. your DOM is not yet ready when the code has been executed.
2. or the DOM with *id="toggle"* does not exists.

if the error scenario is number 1, you can fix it by wrapping you codes in a self invoking function

`$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` or `(function(){ ... })();`

[what are the difference between two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function)

Comment: Here's a demo using $(document).ready(... : http://codepen.io/virmasalo/pen/EydbVw

Answer (score 0):

```
theToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){
   toggleClass(this, 'on');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This might be the solution, but please provide information on WHY this is the answer, so people can actually learn.