# .css() doesn't get correct values at page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am calling `.css()` function at page load with the following code:

```
$(function(){

var positionLeft = parseInt($(".wrapper").css("margin-left"))-50;
if (isNaN(positionLeft)){
    console.log(positionLeft);
}

$("#full-wrapper").css("margin-left",(positionLeft+"px").toString()); 

});
```

For some reason, the positionLeft is always `NaN`. If I use setInterval(fn,1), and ask for a positionLeft just 1ms later, the positionLeft is as expected. What is going on here?

Comment: Try wrapping it in a document.ready(). I think the result would be the same, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: This appears to work. I thought  $(function(){}) is the same as document.ready(). Strange

Comment: But then again,         var sw = $("#workarea-section").width();
is set to undefined, even if I use document.ready

Comment: Check back if the `.wrapper` element has some `margin-left` in the CSS or not. That could be one reason for its not returning a number.

Comment: @sanjihan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function

Comment: @sanjihan I made it an answer .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to chop down that `.toString()` function in the end and make it just like below, as you don't really need `toString()` here—would work without it anyway:

```
$("#full-wrapper").css("margin-left", positionLeft+"px");
```

See it yourself:

```js
$(function() {

  var positionLeft = parseInt($(".wrapper").css("margin-left")) - 50;
  if (isNaN(positionLeft)) {
    console.log(positionLeft);
  }

  $("#full-wrapper").css("margin-left", positionLeft + "px");

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">.wrapper</div>
<div id="full-wrapper">#full-wrapper</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery document.ready vs self calling anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function)

Your self invoking function was a race condition and it looks like it won. Wrap your function in a `document.ready()` to ensure that the document is ready (initialized) before you try to access DOM element values.