# How to call js jQuery from functions.php in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have this code on Wordpress post:

```
<input type=text id="testni" value="la">
```

and this code in functions.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $function(){
        $("#testni").attr("value", "petra");


          }
        </script>
```

This does not work. I guess i have to add some php code?

How to call JS from php?

Comment: `$(function(){
        $("#testni").val("petra");
          })`, Use `.val()` to set value and correct DOM ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#testni").val("petra");
});
</script>
```

[Read about DOM ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259561/9618184)
[Read about setting an input value](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: value in field is still la, it has to be petra

Comment: Then you have another error somewhere else. Also, make sure you have only 1 `id="testni"`.

Comment: I tried on new clean website and it still does not work

Comment: Did you loaded jQuery above this code? Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#testni").val("petra");
});
</script>

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call js in wordpress.. You need to add action in functions.php file. Try the below method.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_footer','custom_script');
function custom_script(){
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          $function(){
        $('#testni').attr('value', 'petra');


          }
        </script>";
}
?>
```

Or else simply add your script in header.php or footer.php.